# Varying behavior of "%s" in wprintf() in different libc implementations

Tags: c, unicode, printf, glibc, newlib

I've noticed that while

```
#include <stdio.h>
wprintf( L"Hello, %s\n", "world" );
```

works with standard glibc under Linux, the same thing does not work the same way with newlib. It seems newlib expects wide string for "%s" there, so the following works instead:

```
wprintf( L"Hello, %s\n", L"world" );
```

Which behavior is the correct one? Is this a bug in newlib? Also, is there a way to explicitly specify that I want a "narrow" string, not a wide one in the printf string format specifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct format specifier for wide strings (`wchar_t *`) is `%ls`, for normal, 'narrow' C strings (`char *`) is `%s`. The implementation of glibc is correct.

Comment: Turned out to be a bug in newlib after all. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that `%ls` the standard way to use wide strings, and `%s` is the standard way to use narrow strings. I don't know about newlib, but Microsoft's `wprintf`, which also incorrectly treats `%s` as meaning a wide string, accepts `%hs` to explicitly specify a narrow string. It also works in glibc because the `h` is ignored. If you are targeting MSVC at all, you might want to use `%hs`.

Source: http://en.chys.info/2009/06/wprintfs/